# How do I change a jar version from a Grails Plugin?

Tags: java, grails, grails-plugin

I am using this Grails plugin:

http://grails.org/plugin/excel-export

Which uses Apache POI. I would like to change the version of Apache POI that it is currently using. What steps do I need to take to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grails provides the ability of exclude some dependency when resolving the plugin. So you can do in your BuildConfig.groovy:

```
dependencies {
  //version need to be replaced to the desired value
  compile('org.apache.poi:poi:version') 
  compile('org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:version')
}

plugins {
  compile(":excel-export:0.1.7") {
    //list of dependencies declared inside the plugin that will be ignored.
    excludes 'poi', 'poi-ooxml' 
  }
}
```

Comment: `excludes 'poi', 'poi-ooxml'` is sufficient my dear friend. ;)